# Getting microsecond from MySQL divide by 1000

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I am getting a strange behavior when reading a datetime(3) field from MySQL. The microseconds are coming divided by 1000. For example, I have the following datetime `2019-10-06 02:08:48.100`. When I read this data using the mysql connector I get the datetime microseconds as 100 not 1000000, and when I apply the `strftime` method with the following format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` I get `2019-10-06 02:08:48.000100`. Does anyone knows what can be the cause of this?

Comment: 1000000/1000 = 1000

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I found the problem. It is because datetime(3) is for millisecond precision. As datetime in python works with microsecond I need my MySQL DB to use datetime(6).